# PHP - Extract characters before and after first space

Tags: php, regex, string

Can't seem to get this one.  I would like to get the first 2 characters from the word before the first space and first 3 characters after the first space.

Not sure if break up the word in [0], [1] would work, but regex might work.

```
$string = "Bobby Ryan";
$output = 'BoRya';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried?

suggestion: explode() your string on the space character, get the first and last values in the array by index, then use substr() to fetch the characters you require.

Comment: Happens to me ever time, I post and wait for the answer.  In the mean time I figure it out.....

Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: ha, always the way, what did you come up with? place it under your original question. Do you need to account for "First Middle Last" names?

Answer (score 1):

This should work correctly.

```
   $string = 'Bobby Ryan';

   $words = explode(" ", $string);
   $output = substr($words[0], 0, 2) . substr($words[1], 0, 3);

   echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

From `explode()`'s manual entry: (http://www.php.net/explode) - `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )`.

the optional `$limit` parameter indicates into how many pieces the string should be exploded to, and considering what you want to achieve, along with `substr()`(http://www.php.net/substr):

```
list($beforeSpace, $afterSpace) = explode(" ", $string, 2);
$output = substr($beforeSpace, 0, 2) . substr($afterSpace, 0, 3);
```

will break the string into two strings right at the first space character, and then form the output from the first two characters of whatever was before the space, and the first three characters of whatever was after the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Bobby Ryan";
$var=explode(" ",$string);
// Totally didnt debug this part, may have to change 2 and 3 to -1 to 1 and 2
$output = substr($var[0],0,2) +  substr($var[1],0,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first split the string into parts. Look at explode or some kind of String tokinizer. You must then use a substring function to get parts of the strings.

```
$string = "Bobby Ryan";
$output = getPartsOfString($string, 2, 3);
echo $output;

function getPartsOfString($string, $firstNumOfChars, $secondNumOfChars) {
{
    $part = explode(" ", $string);

    // Get substrings from parts
    return substr($part[0], 0, $firstNumOfChars).substr($part[1], 0, $secondNumOfChars);
}
```

The function could have several more parameter. The start of first and second string. (The 0s in substring function) and a spesified delimiter. (Change to explode($delimiter, $string);

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex only:

```
$string = "Bobby Ryan";
$output = preg_replace("/(\w{2})\w* (\w{3})\w*/", "$1$2", $string);
```

Comment: Actually you probably should use `$output = preg_replace("/\s*(\w{1,2})\w*\s+(\w{1,2}).*/", "$1$2", $string);`.

Breakdown:
-\s* match any whitespaces before first word
-(\w{1,2}) first one (if the word has only one character) or two characters of first word
-\w* any remaining characters (if any)
-\s+ at least one whitespace character
-(\w{1,2}) first one (if the word has only one character) or two characters of the second word
-.* rest of the string